# Quelle est signification "app-driven" dans ce contexte

Tags: sens

J’aimerais bien savoir si **"app-driven"** veut dire : **"Axé sur l'application"** dans le contexte suivant:

**An app-driven approach to understand Android**

Comment: Il faut faire attention à l'ambiguité sous-jacente, à savoir que application peut vouloir dire "app(lication) = programme", mais aussi "application = mise en pratique." Ceci peut donc être interprété comme une approche "applicative/de mise en application", qui en français paraît très logique, et pour laquelle la version anglaise ne fait aucun doute.

Comment: Ce n'est pas une question qui concerne la langue française

Answer (score 1):

Si vous l'avez lu dans [cet article](http://www.deitel.com/Books/Android/AndroidforProgrammers/tabid/3606/Default.aspx) à propos du livre du même nom, les premières lignes :

> Billions of apps have been downloaded from Android Market! This book gives you everything you’ll need to start developing great Android apps quickly and getting them published on Android Market.

Me permettent de traduire plutôt par *"**orienté sur la création d'application**"*.

En sous-entendant que création implique aussi conception, gestion et commercialisation (business model) et qu'en parlant d'application, on parle d'applications mobiles.

Answer (score 1):

"App-driven" exprime le fait que les applications fournissent le fil conducteur pour apprendre/comprendre le système d'exploitation Android. Je propose donc

> Comprendre Android par le biais des app(lication)s

ou pour être plus proche de l'original

> Comprendre Android sous la conduite des app(lication)s.